# How to find distance between two coordinate using javascript with Driving mode

Tags: javascript, distance

i tried this

```js
function distance(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) 
{
 var R = 6371; // km (change this constant to get miles)
 var dLat = (lat2-lat1) * Math.PI / 180;
 var dLon = (lon2-lon1) * Math.PI / 180;
 var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI / 180 ) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI / 180 ) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
 var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
 var d = R * c;
 if (d>1) return Math.round(d)+"km";
 else if (d<=1) return Math.round(d*1000)+"m";
 return d;
}
```

distance(21.1702401,72.83106070000008,22.3038945,70.80215989999999);

using above function i m getting this output : 245km

result coming for Straight Distance :245km

but i need Driving mode ditance of that location and its output should be 448km

From value is : Surat, Gujarat, India
to value is  :Rajkot, Gujarat, India

so pls help me to solve this.. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Driving directions cannot be "simply" calculated. You need to know the roads, how long they are, where you can turn off and lots more.

**It is too complicated to do in a single function with no underlying data.**

I would suggest you look into Google maps API or find if TomTom/Apple/Garmin have APIs for their map data.